# State change, trace discrepancies

Tags: state, trace

I'm finding several ETH transactions where the state changes do not match the traces and I cannot figure out why.

For instance, in the transaction below the traces show a transfer of 0.421827016959665207 ETH to 0xe87e15b9c7d989474cb6d8c56b3db4efad5b21e8, but in the state changes it goes to 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x01df6b7e7245f581cb6b7bc59a6c2c1ebec0b0c54dde313e64f8bbc91c39b2d9

If I look at the balances of both addresses, it seems that the ETH never arrives in 0xe87e15b9c7d989474cb6d8c56b3db4efad5b21e8, so the state changes seem to be correct. Is this intended? And if so, why do the traces not reflect the state changes?